# Current location span changes to random number on map kit view

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

i have a map kit view and when the app loads, it gets the users current location and tracks it. It then runs a function to focus on the users location which I've also linked to a button so the user can navigate around and then focus back to their location span.

In this function i set the span to 0.01 but when i print the span value its different. When the app runs and focuses for the first time, the latitude span is printing at 0.00745918279325508

Then when i hit the focus button which runs the exact same function, the lat span is printing at 0.0102124663369167 and its noticeably zoomed out

Why is it doing this when I've already set it to 0.01? here is my code:

```
    @IBAction func focusLocation(sender: UIButton)
    {
        snapLocation()
    }

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
        {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            snapLocation()
        }
    }

    func snapLocation()
    {
        let currentLocation = locationManager.location?.coordinate

        let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = (currentLocation?.latitude)!
        let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = (currentLocation?.longitude)!

        let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
        let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

        mapkitView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple docs:

> When setting a new region, the map may adjust the value in the region
>   parameter so that it fits the visible area of the map precisely. This
>   is normal and is done to ensure that the value in the region property
>   always reflects the visible portion of the map. However, it does mean
>   that if you get the value of that property right after calling this
>   method, the returned value may not match the value you set.

So, when you apply span, it creates the region which is best fit for your request. It will not be exactly same as what you have requested.